# Help on listings packages

Tags: listings, linenumber

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{emptypage}%amd for no page number on empty page
\usepackage{etoc}%amd for multiple tocs
\usepackage{upquote}%amd for upright single quote
\usepackage{textcomp}%amd for upright quote symbols

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\tcbset{mybox/.style={
  before={\par\vskip3ex\noindent},
  after={\par\vskip1.5ex}}}


\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\definecolor{mylightgrey}{rgb}{0.98, 0.98, 0.98}
\definecolor{mydarkgrey}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, 0.3}

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
%language=LaTeX,
% Basic style
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
commentstyle=\slshape\footnotesize, %\rmfamily
stringstyle=\ttfamily\slshape\small,
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\footnotesize,
numberfirstline=false,
numbersep=1em,
stepnumber=3,
% Margins and box
framextopmargin=2em,
framexbottommargin=2em,
frame=l,
backgroundcolor=\color{mylightgrey},
xleftmargin=1em,
tabsize=4,
% Show spaces
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=fullflexible,
breaklines=true,
% Comments
morecomment=[l]{\%},
% Keywords
keywordstyle=\color{mydarkgrey}\bfseries,
escapechar={§},
%alsoletter={_, .},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={end, table, figure, item, description, document, graphicspath, tableofcontents, documentclass,
setends, showsequencelogo, feature, showruler, hidenumbering, texshade, setdoublesep, setatomsep, chemname, chemfig},
sensitive=true,
% Built-in
emphstyle=\color{mydarkgrey}\bfseries,
emph={maketitle, tableofcontents, input, addcontentsline,addpenalty,addtocontents,%
      addtocounter,addtolength,addtoversion,addvspace,alph,Alph,%
      arabic,array,arraycolsep,arrayrulewidth,arraystretch,%
      baselinestretch,begin,bezier,bfseries,bibcite,bibdata,bibitem,%
      bibliography,bibliographystyle,bibstyle,bigskip,boldmath,%
      botfigrule,bottomfraction,Box,caption,center,chapter, CheckCommand,circle,%
      citation,cite,cleardoublepage,clearpage,cline,columnsep,%
      columnseprule,columnwidth,contentsline,dashbox,date,dblfigrule,%
      dblfloatpagefraction,dblfloatsep,dbltextfloatsep,dbltopfraction,%
      defaultscriptratio,defaultscriptscriptratio,depth,Diamond,%
      displaymath,documentclass,documentstyle,doublerulesep,%
      em,emph,endarray,endcenter,enddisplaymath,enddocument,%
      endenumerate,endeqnarray,endequation,endflushleft,endflushright,%
      enditemize,endlist,endlrbox,endmath,endminipage,endpicture,%
      endsloppypar,endtabbing,endtabular,endtrivlist,endverbatim,%
      enlargethispage,ensuremath,enumerate,eqnarray,%equation,%
      evensidemargin,extracolsep,fbox,fboxrule,fboxsep,filecontents,%
      fill,floatpagefraction,floatsep,flushbottom,%flushleft,flushright,%
      fnsymbol,fontencoding,fontfamily,fontseries,fontshape,fontsize,%
      fontsubfuzz,footnotemark,footnotesep,footnotetext,footskip,frac,%
      frame,framebox,fussy,glossary,headheight,headsep,height,hline,%
      hspace,include,includeonly,index,inputlineno,intextsep,%
      itemindent,itemize,itemsep,iterate,itshape,Join,kill,label,%
      labelsep,labelwidth,LaTeX,LaTeXe,leadsto,lefteqn,leftmargin,%
      leftmargini,leftmarginii,leftmarginiii,leftmarginiv,leftmarginv,%
      leftmarginvi,leftmark,lhd,lim,linebreak,linespread,linethickness,%
      linewidth,list,listfiles,listfiles,listparindent,lrbox,%
      makeatletter,makeatother,makebox,makeglossary,makeindex,%
      makelabel,MakeLowercase,MakeUppercase,marginpar,marginparpush,%
      marginparsep,marginparwidth,markboth,markright,math,mathbf,%
      mathellipsis,mathgroup,mathit,mathrm,mathsf,mathsterling,mathtt,%
      mathunderscore,mathversion,mbox,mdseries,mho,minipage,%
      multicolumn,multiput,NeedsTeXFormat,newcommand,newcounter,%
      newenvironment,newfont,newhelp,newlabel,newlength,newline,%
      newmathalphabet,newpage,newsavebox,newtheorem,nobreakspace,%
      nobreakspace,nocite,nocorr,nocorrlist,nofiles,nolinebreak,%
      nonumber,nopagebreak,normalcolor,normalfont,normalmarginpar,%
      numberline,obeycr,oddsidemargin,oldstylenums,onecolumn,oval,%
      pagebreak,pagenumbering,pageref,pagestyle,paperheight,paperwidth,%
      paragraph, paragraphmark,parbox,parsep,partopsep,picture,poptabs,pounds,%
      protect,pushtabs,put,qbezier,qbeziermax,raggedleft,raisebox,%
      ref,refstepcounter,renewcommand,renewenvironment,restorecr,%
      reversemarginpar,rhd,rightmargin,rightmark,rmfamily,roman,Roman,%
      rootbox,rule,samepage,sbox,scshape,secdef,section,sectionmark,%
      selectfont,setcounter,settodepth,settoheight,settowidth,sffamily,%
      shortstack,showoutput,showoverfull,sloppy,sloppypar,slshape,%
      smallskip,sqsubset,sqsupset,SS,stackrel,stepcounter,stop,stretch,%
      subparagraph, subparagraphmark,subsection, subsubsection, subsectionmark,subsubsectionmark,sum,%
      suppressfloats,symbol,tabbing,tabbingsep,tabcolsep,tabular,%
      tabularnewline,textasciicircum,textasciitilde,textbackslash,%
      textbar,textbf,textbraceleft,textbraceright,textbullet,%
      textcircled,textcompwordmark,textdagger,textdaggerdbl,textdollar,%
      textellipsis,textemdash,textendash,textexclamdown,textfloatsep,%
      textfraction,textgreater,textheight,textit,textless,textmd,%
      textnormal,textparagraph,textperiodcentered,textquestiondown,%
      textquotedblleft,textquotedblright,textquoteleft,textquoteright,%
      textregistered,textrm,textsc,textsection,textsf,textsl,%
      textsterling,textsuperscript,texttrademark,texttt,textunderscore,%
      textup,textvisiblespace,textwidth,thanks,thefootnote,thempfn,%
      thempfn,thempfootnote,thepage,thepage,thicklines,thinlines,%
      thispagestyle,today,topfigrule,topfraction,topmargin,%
      topsep,totalheight,tracingfonts,trivlist,ttfamily,twocolumn,%
      typein,typeout,unboldmath,unitlength,unlhd,unrhd,upshape,usebox,%
      usecounter,usefont,usepackage,vector,verb,verbatim,vline,%
      vspace,%width,%
      normalsize,small,footnotesize,scriptsize,tiny,large,Large,LARGE,%
      huge,Huge, moderncvstyle, moderncvcolor, newcites, firstname, familyname, address,%
      phone, email, homepage, makecvtitle, cventry, nocitepubs, bibliographystylepubs,%
      nociteprep, bibliographypubs, bibliographystyleprep, bibliographyprep, cvitem,%
      lim, sum, infty, underline, author, \title, includegraphics, item, quad}
}

\lstnewenvironment{shorttexcode}{\lstset{style=mylatexstyle}}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{shorttexcode}
\documentclass{report}

% load desired packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Specify the directory where pictures are stored
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Your short or long thesis §title§}}
\author{Your Name}

% let LaTeX produce the title and §\textit{\footnotesize table}§ of contents
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{introduction}
\input{methods}
\input{results}
\input{discussion}

\end{document}
\end{shorttexcode}


\end{document}
```

Output generated as:

[image]

But the required output as:

[image]

You can see the difference in line numbers, how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know why, maybe one of the experts has an answer to that, but just adding `firstnumber=1`to your `\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}` does the trick. To me this behavior seems odd. Shouldn't `auto` work as well (but doesn't)? Looking into `listings.sty`, I cannot figure out, what's wrong (I don't understand the code), that's why I did not post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must explicitly set `firstnumber`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
stepnumber=3,
firstnumber=1
}

\lstnewenvironment{shorttexcode}{\lstset{style=mylatexstyle}}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{shorttexcode}
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
\end{shorttexcode}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In some cases, I need to start the line numbers from 2 and increment by three, for this I've used the same tagging as \lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
stepnumber=3,
firstnumber=2
}
But it was not working, can you suggest what went wrong in my tag?